# Java Web Service Client which access the .Net Webservice

Tags: java, soap, webservice-client

I'm trying to access online .Net Webservice through Java Webservice client.

But unfortunately, am getting an error "**Connection timed out: connect**"

Below is my code:

```
import org.apache.axis.client.Call;
import org.apache.axis.client.Service;
import javax.xml.namespace.QName;

public class WebServiceMain {

    public static void main(String[] args) {

         try {
                 String endpoint = "http://wsf.cdyne.com/SpellChecker/check.asmx";
                 Service service = new Service();
                 Call call = (Call)service.createCall();
                 call.setProperty(Call.SOAPACTION_USE_PROPERTY, new Boolean(true)); 
                     call.setProperty(Call.SOAPACTION_URI_PROPERTY, "http://ws.cdyne.com/CheckTextBodyV2");
                     call.setTargetEndpointAddress( new java.net.URL(endpoint) );
                     call.setPortName(new QName("http://ws.cdyne.com/", "check"));
                 call.setOperationName(new QName("http://ws.cdyne.com/", "CheckTextBodyV2"));

                 System.out.println(call.invoke(new Object[] {"helo is my name"}));
               } catch (Exception e) {
                 System.err.println(e.toString());
               }
    }
}
```

Comment: can you connect to that service (with e.g. a browser)?

Comment: @Mat: Yes, I'm able to connect through browser and getting XML results. But if I'm accessing through this code, am not.

Answer (score 0):

Connection timeout comes because of network issues.try to acess URL in browser.also try to append ?wsdl at the end of URL,you should see the wsdl.if this doesn't work troubleshoot network settings.

Comment: Yes, I'm able to connect through browser and getting XML results.

Answer (score 0):

> Connection timed out: connect

This means that your client application cannot even talk to the Web Service. This is not a programmatic issue.

Check and see whether you can access the end-point through your web browser. If not, then that service is not available. So it doesn't work.

If your browser can access it, and if you are connecting to Internet through a proxy, then you need to specify the proxy details to Java Client. To do that, you can use  -Dhttp.proxyHost=10.2.240.11 and -Dhttp.proxyPort=8080 (replace with your values) system properties when you start up your client application.

Comment: @Yohan: I have set the property for proxy host & port. But still it is the same.
`System.setProperty("http.proxyHost", "XXXXXXXXXXXXX");
System.setProperty("http.proxyPort", "80");`

Comment: Is my code is executing on your machine? Please check & let me know.

Comment: @Siva If you are using a proxy server, then I suspect this has to be because of that. Do you need authentication for your proxy server ? 

I noticed that you are using Axis as the Web Service client. This link also states the necessary system properties to get Axis to connect through a Proxy : http://publib.boulder.ibm.com/infocenter/ledoc/v6r2/index.jsp?topic=/com.ibm.rcp.tools.doc.admin/coinfiguringapacheaxisclientproxysettings.html

Comment: @Siva Yes, it runs in my machine. But it fails when it de-serializes the XML content, which is another issue. But yes, the Web Service call goes through. It has to be your proxy settings.

Comment: I am not an Axis expert, but I think you should check the binding style associated with your dynamic client. If it is feasible, try to use the WSDL2Java tool in Axis toolkit to build the client for you and try invoking the WS through that.

Answer (score 0):

Download the soapui software and get installed it.
then load the wsdl file and create the project.

Then test your web service via soap ui.
you can edit the connection timeout  value of the soap ui. chane it for big vlue and test.still your getiong time out ping to the ip addres of the service

Comment: please provide the url to download soapui software. So I can try with that too.